# bot.wait_for_reaction () with multiple reaction using custom emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'test')
    emoji1 = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='bow')
    emoji2 = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='arrow')
    await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji1)
    await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji2)
    res = await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji=[emoji1,emoji2], message=msg, user=ctx.message.author)
    if res:
        reaction, ctx.message.author = res
        if str(reaction.emoji) == ":bow:521854323022495747":
        ##stuffs
        if str(reaction.emoji) == ":arrow:521913180180447246":
        ##stuffs
```

My command is working, but when I react in an emoji, I can not react in the second, what should I do so I can react in both?
I can only react one at a time, if I want to react in another emoji, I would have to use the command again.
Please, complete answers

Comment: It's not super clear what you're asking.  You could loop waiting for the reaction for as long there are reactions that haven't been used yet, maybe with some timeout to prevent old sessions from lasting a long time.

Comment: Wait, is not that clear? I wrote perfectly what the problem is causing under the command. When I click on an emoji, it executes the command, but I can not react on the second emoji, that's the problem, I would have to execute the command again so I can click on the second emoji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen for a reaction again after the first time, the easiest way is to put the reaction listening logic in a loop.  The below loop listens for reactions in the list and removes them as it sees them.  That way someone can't use the arrow reaction more than once, for example.

```
msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'test')
emoji1 = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='bow')
emoji2 = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='arrow')
await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji1)
await bot.add_reaction(msg, emoji2)
emojis = [emoji1, emoji2]
while emojis:
    res = await bot.wait_for_reaction(emoji=emojis, message=msg, user=ctx.message.author)
    if res:
        reaction, user = res
        emojis = [e for e in emojis if e != reaction]
        if reaction.emoji == emoji1:
            #stuffs
        if reaction.emoji == emoji2:
            #stuffs
```

Comment: Dosent work for me